# Разница между полями в выборке

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть такая выборка:

```
o = Otchet.where("issue_number = ?", 118799)

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Otchet id: 2, issue_number: 118799, 
 assigned_to_id: 279, created_at: "2016-08-24 11:53:52", 
 updated_at: "2016-08-24 11:53:52">, #<Otchet id: 3, 
 issue_number: 118799, assigned_to_id: 1236, created_at: "2016-08-24 11:54:33", 
 updated_at: "2016-08-24 11:54:33">, #<Otchet id: 4, issue_number: 118799,
 assigned_to_id: 2743, created_at: "2016-08-24 12:18:07", updated_at: "2016-08-24 12:18:07">]>
```

Подскажите как мне обработать данную выборку, чтобы на выходе подсчиталось время между created_at. Т.е. в данном случае есть 3 элемента, у которых:

```
created_at1: "2016-08-24 11:53:52"
created_at2: "2016-08-24 11:54:33"
created_at3: "2016-08-24 12:18:07"
```

Надо получить разницы: `created_at2 - created_at1, created_at3 - created_at2, Time.now - created_at3`. Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: Тяжело. Это даже на SQL пишется не слишком-то красиво. ActiveRecord'овский язык запросов тут, скорее всего, сам не вытянет.

Comment: @D-side, так мне и не надо ActiveRecord задействовать, я им просто выбрал данные, а дальше думал что-то подобное: `o.each do |time| какая-то логика end`

Comment: М... понял вас. Хотя считать это не базой может быть нехорошо, считать базой может быть ещё хуже ._.

Comment: @D-side, не подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все способы считать это на уровне БД, которые я могу представить, страшноваты, медленны или ненадёжны. Попробуем на уровне Ruby.

`ActiveRecord::Relation` является `Enumerable`. А потому имеет метод [`Enumerable#each_cons(n)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) (*each consecutive*, каждые последовательные), передающий в свой блок **полные** наборы по `n` элементов (если элементов меньше, набор не выдаётся), с каждым шагом сдвигаясь вперёд по одному.

Массив тоже `Enumerable`, и пример на нём (из документации) достаточно нагляден:

```
(1..10).each_cons(3) { |a| p a }
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
```

Сделав `.each_cons(2)` вы получите итератор по последовательным парам объектов. Поскольку в аргументе блока всегда будет массив, его можно **разложить** (destructure) в отдельные переменные:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16].each_cons(2) do |(before, after)| # внимание, круглые скобки
  # Пара круглых скобок в списке аргументов чего бы там ни было раскладывает одно значение.
  # ...если это массив или его .to_ary возвращает массив. Здесь мы знаем размер массива и
  # что в нём точно есть 2 элемента, но если бы мы не были уверены, вместо недостающих
  # был бы nil, а лишние бы попросту потерялись.
  puts("#{after} - #{before} = #{after - before}")
end
# 4 - 1 = 3
# 9 - 4 = 5
# 16 - 9 = 7
# => nil
```

Этот метод можно применить и к `ActiveRecord::Relation`, получая наборы из отдельных записей. Вперёд!

...только не забудьте, что для `N` объектов у вас будет `N - 1` разностей. Как это обрабатывать, уже ваше дело.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение я бы все-таки предложил традиционное SQL-решение, отталкиваясь от следующего SQL-запроса

```
SELECT
  fst.id,
  fst.created_at - snd.created_at AS diff
FROM
  otchets AS fst
LEFT JOIN
  otchets AS snd
ON
  fst.id = snd.id + 1
ORDER BY
  fst.id;
```

Для этого в модель отчет следует ввести виртуальное поле `diff`, в котором мы будем хранить разницу между предыдущими и последующими интервалами времени

```
class Otchet < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def diff
    self[:diff]
  end
  ...
end
```

Тогда представленный выше SQL-запрос можно получить следующим образом

```
col = Otchet
  .select('otchets.id, otchets.created_at - snd.created_at AS diff')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN otchets AS snd ON otchets.id = snd.id + 1')
  .order('otchets.id')

p col.collect(&:diff)
=> [nil, "00:00:00.009453", "00:00:00.009968"]
```

К сожалению представленное выше решение расчитано только на последовательную и неразрывную последовательность идентификаторов `id`. Обойти это можно воспользовавшись переменными MySQL (оконные функции, MySQL, к сожалению, не поддерживает). К сожалению, получающийся запрос довольно "многоэтажен", вероятно нет смысла переводить его в ActiveRecord (разве что использовать его в качестве чистого SQL-запроса).

```
SELECT
  map.id,
  map.prev_id,
  lft.created_at - rgt.created_at AS diff
FROM
  (SELECT
    @prev_id AS prev_id,
    (@prev_id := id) AS id
  FROM
    otchets,
    (SELECT @prev_id := null) AS var_init) AS map
LEFT JOIN
  otchets AS lft
ON
  lft.id = map.id
LEFT JOIN
  otchets AS rgt
ON
  rgt.id = map.prev_id
WHERE
  map.prev_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: ...и оно рассчитывает, что нумерация `id` будет последовательной и непрерывной. Стоит это ограничение упомянуть.

Comment: @D-side да есть такое дело, попробую подумать еще и представить более универсальное решение. Если не получится добавлю ваше замечание в решение.

Comment: Я некогда тоже его разыскивал. Лучшее, что нашёл: [`LAG` из MSSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh231256.aspx), который позволяет ссылаться "назад".

Comment: С помощью оконных функций можно зарулить почти любую такую задачу, жалко в MySQL их нет и наверное уже вряд ли появятся.

Comment: @cheops, спасибо за ваше решение, но мне лучше воспользоватся реализацией на ruby